# Angular components and directives autocomplete in vim

Tags: angular, vim

Is there a way to autocomplete Angular directives and components in Vim while working with html templates?

Comment: Have you tried this https://vimawesome.com/plugin/javascript-libraries-syntax?

Comment: It is for AngularJS. I need solution for Angular 2+

Comment: What about this? https://github.com/Quramy/tsuquyomi and https://github.com/mhartington/vim-angular2-snippets

Comment: @TheChetan neither of those two does not add components and directives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not perfect but Deoplete is probably as good as it gets. In my use case it's pretty good at picking up keywords you've used and autocompleting those. It works with html. Requires either Vim8 or Neovim. I personally can't recommend Neovim enough.

https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim

Answer (score 4):

An Angular language service [coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) [extension](https://github.com/iamcco/coc-angular) for (neo)vim

https://github.com/iamcco/coc-angular

> This extension provides a rich editing experience for Angular
>   templates, both inline and external templates including:
>
> - Completions lists
> - AOT Diagnostic messages
> - Quick info
> - Go to definition